# admin password for viki

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just downloaded the ROS Groovy Galapagos VM bundled with Ubuntu and the Administrator is 'Viki'. When my laptop recovers from sleep it wants a password. Any chance of making the password public?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65830/admin-password-for-viki/) by [dave_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/5221/dave_g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found answer. Password is same as user name: 'viki'. Stupid system won't let me post link to article but it's an article on nootrix.com about virtualizing ros.

---

Originally posted by [dave_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/5221/dave_g/) with karma: 46 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2